# full page background color angular

Tags: angular

Try as I might I can't find a way to style the full page in Angular.  All my templates exist in their own tiny little world that is some kind of subset

```
html {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

does not work.  I tried getting my template to fill the to the parent's height/width, but that also did not work.  It still only fills partially.  It almost hits the edges on the sides and top, but stops where the last div reaches toward the bottom.

```
.whatever {
    background-color: lightblue;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in projects generated with the angular-cli you should have a styles.css (scss if you chose sass on generating the project) directly in src/styles.css

if you add the following css to it, the background will be styled accordingly:

```
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

good luck!

@edit:

the reason, you cannot style the body tag from within a component's css file is the shadow dom. the shadow dom ensures, that the styles are specific to the according component which most of the time is useful (if you want to use the same class name for different styling rules of different components)

the following page might clarify things a bit more for you:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html#!#special-selectors

Comment: Thank you for explaining the cause of the issue.  I still can't seem to get it to work the way I would like.  According to the documentation :host /deep/ should work, but sadly it isn't working for me.  I've resorted to putting a large absolute div with z-index -100 and width/height at 100%

Comment: it should not be necessary to use :host /deep/ if you place the css rule (body tag without :host or deep) in the global css file (src/styles.css). if this still doesnt work, try to give a class to your body tag (e.g. 'color-lightblue') and style this class within the src/styles.css file.